# Jackson conflicting property and getter definitions

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm extending following third-party class which I can't change:

```
public class Page {
    @JsonProperty("content")
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {};
}
```

My implementation of Page looks like this:

```
public class MyPage extends Page {
    @JsonProperty("my-content")
    public String getContent() {return super.getContent()};
}
```

When I'm trying to serialize instance of MyPage class I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting property name definitions:  
'content' (for [field com.test.Page#content]) 
vs
'my-content' (for [method com.test.MyPage#getContent(0 params)])
```

Is there an easy way to force serializer to produce 'my-content' property?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with the Jackson versions I'm using, can you add yours? to try to reproduce, Jackson 1.9.13 behaves as expected, Jackson 2.5.2 prints `{"my-content":"blah","content":null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue was solved in Jackson 2.4.0. Please check https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/193.

Try to update your Jackson library to 2.4.0 or above.